# An obstruction like ETH

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, subset-sum

We know under $ETH$ we cannot solve $K$-SUM in $f(K)poly(nK)$ time under any function $f(K)$ (usually $2^{O(K)}$).

Is there any conjecture that prevents a $(\log n)^{O(K)}$ complexity (this is entirely consistent with possibility as $K=\Omega(n)$ we need exponential time for subset sum) or is such possibility allowed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ETH itself precludes this possibility.

In https://people.csail.mit.edu/rrw/cnf-sat-feasible.pdf
 we show that any $n^{O(1)} n^{k/\alpha(k)}$ time algorithm for k-SUM, for any monotone nondecreasing unbounded function $\alpha$, would imply ETH is false.

Comment: Do you mean that $\alpha$ is strictly increasing, or at least goes to infinity?

Comment: @RyanWilliams Similar in spirit to ETH like obstruction. Is there anything that would prevent $O((\log n)^{O(k)})$ complexity with polynomial size advice or a PPAD oracle?

Comment: Added "unbounded" :)

Comment: @Brout Note that (log(n))^k is an FPT function, so yeah, ETH rules that out. With poly size advice it would mean subexponential size circuits for 3sat. With a PPAD oracle it would seem to imply that ETH implies PPAD not in P.  To me that would be a breakthrough, I don't know of much corroborating evidence that PPAD isn't in P